# Having trouble with UITableViewCell loaded from nib

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nib

I am having trouble wiht UITableViewCell loaded from nib. I used apple documentation to that but I do't know where I am going wrong. UITableViewCell created through IB contains 5 UIlable. Nib are loaded perfectly but the problem is when I scroll text of the label changes automatically to different.
Following is the my code for cell for row at indexpath. Please let me know where I am going worng.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
int rowNo = [indexPath row];
NSLog(@"Row No:%d",rowNo);
Transfer *tempTransferRecord =(Transfer*)[self.transferInformation objectAtIndex:rowNo];
seasonYear.text=tempTransferRecord.seasonYear;
longName.text=tempTransferRecord.longName;
transactionDate.text=tempTransferRecord.transactionDate;
toTeam.text=tempTransferRecord.toTeam;
fromTeam.text=tempTransferRecord.fromTeam;
/*
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier2";    
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier] ;

if (cell == nil) 
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PlayerTransfers" owner:self options:nil];
    cell=transfersInfoCell;
    self.transfersInfoCell=nil;
}

 */


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier2";
static NSString *CellNib = @"PlayerTransfers";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (UITableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

// perform additional custom work...

return cell;

}
```

Comment: Make sure the `File's Owner` object of your `UITableViewCell` in Interface Builder is set to the class you wrote the above code in. Also, I would use the commented-out version of cell loading rather than the one you currently use; add a `transfersInfoCell` property to the class with the table view and link it in the table view cell's interface definition. If the @property you define is not explicitly (`assign`), you should also remove the `self.` before `transfersInfoCell=nil`.

Comment: I did all of it all ready. Identifier in IB is MyIdentifier2, @property is (nonatomic,assign). I am getting nibs in Table only problem is, labels on that UItableviewcell changing their text when I scroll it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your cell loading code to the top of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and the `rowNo` and value setting after that. Cells changing content must mean you're either changing what's in the data source between when you first set it and when you scroll, or you're setting values at the wrong point in time (i.e setting values on row 5 but then loading row 6 from a nib, or setting values on a row but then loading the nib for it afterwards so the values you set are overridden). Also, I'm a bit concerned that you set local variables rather than, say, `(PlayerTransfers*)cell.seasonYear.text = tempTransferRecord.seasonYear` or `(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1].text = tempTransferRecord.seasonYear`. Shouldn't you be setting the values within each cell rather than on your table view class? That could explain why values are changing to something different: you may use the same variables to set every cell.

Comment: Here is what I did ... I created 5 UILabels in TableViewController class and made them property (nonatomic,retain) and later I synthesized it in implementation file. transferInformation is an NSmutable array which holds an record for each players transfer from one team to another team. This record contain 5 fields. Season, longName, transactiondate,toteam and fromteam. Now at cellforrowatIndexpath I am creating temporary record and pulling out its information from transferinformation array based upon index. This info is assigned to UIlabels that I created earlier.

Comment: Based on that, though, you only ever need to show 1 player transfer on screen at a time, and the information isn't being shown in a table view cell. If you intended it to be shown in a table view cell, don't create `UILabel`s in the `UITableViewController` class, create them in the `UITableViewCell` class and set the values of them in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Hey It worked, I created new UITableViewCell for it and put all lables down there and it worked. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Text is not changing now but when I go back to Players list and check for other palyers transfer record then it crashes saying BadAccess.. :(

Comment: For a BAD_ACCESS error you need to check where you `retain` and `release` your variables. That's a different issue, though feel free to create another question about that :) Before you do though, I would suggest you read about [Memory management basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MemoryManagement.html) and the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i).

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a `CellIdentifier` in Interface Builder?